# disable rotation of shape

Tags: javascript, vrml

I have two shapes and I want to disable the rotation of one of theme. What's the best way to do that?

```
    # A Cylinder
 Shape {
     appearance Appearance {
         material Material {
    diffuseColor 0.75 0.5 1.0
            specularColor 0.7 0.7 0.8
            shininess 0.1
         }
     }
     geometry Cylinder {
         height 0.2
         radius 3.
     }
 }
# A Sphere
Shape {
     appearance Appearance {
         material Material { 
         diffuseColor 0.2 0.5 0.75
         transparency 0.0
     }
     }
geometry Sphere {
    radius 1.0
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is only two Shape nodes where you define the appearance and geometry (a Sphere and a Cylinder). There's nothing in the code that would make any of the Shapes rotating.

If you want to get rid of a rotation then you have to search for the corresponding ROUTE going to one of the Shapes. Again, your code doesn't have any DEF which means there's no route that might rotate any of your shape.

By default, a Shape doesn't rotate by itself unless a route is specified or, of course, a piece of script is written.